# Jquery ajax не работает в Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

Здравствуйте! У меня почему-то отказывается работать ajax в Firefox: [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/69PrR/2/)

```
$().ready(
    function() {  
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://ru.smart-ip.net/geoip-json/',
            data: { lang: 'ru', host: '46.50.175.146' },   
            dataType: 'jsonp',    
            success:
                function (data) {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(data);            
                },
            error:
                function (data) {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(data);            
                },
            complete:
                function (data) {
                    console.log('complete');
                    console.log(data);            
                }
        }); 
 });
```

Этот код прекрасно работает в Chrome, но вообще никак не отрабатывает в Firefox (28 версия, ОС - Windows 7). То есть не срабатывает ни функция success ни error ни complete. Это происходит если запускать этот код на jsfiddle.

А вот когда я запускаю этот код из своего веб приложения то в Chrome он также отрабатывает нормально а в Firefox функция заходит в error где объект data выглядит так

[image]

Что я делаю не так и как заставить этот ajax нормально работать в Firefox? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какая версия FireFox? Пробовали повторить запрос с отключенными аддонами? Вот результат запуска в 27.0.1:  

    city: "Новосибирск" 
    countryCode: "RU" 
    countryName: "Россия" 
    host: "46.50.175.146" 
    lang: "ru" 
    latitude: "55.0415" 
    longitude: "82.9346" 
    region: "Новосибирская область"
    source: "smart-ip.net"
    timezone: "Asia/Novosibirsk"

Comment: @VenZell версия Firefox указана в вопросе

Comment: @JuniorTwo, обновил Firefox до версии 28.0.  
Результат:  

    Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success", ещё...}

Все работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, проблема в AdBlock. Во всяком случае, после его отключения ваш запрос сработал нормально. А вот при включенном AdBlock'e наблюдалась описанная вами картина

Comment: @DreamChild, на самом деле, уже не в первый раз замечаю, что либо Ghostery, либо AdBlock блокируют левые запросы. Почему сразу и посоветовал автору попробовать повторить запрос с отключенными аддонами.

Comment: @VenZell адблок тут недавно и вовсе обвиняли в искажении поисковой выдачи Яндекса (причем в намеренном искажении - разработчики адблока якобы так наказали Яндекс за отказ платить за то, чтобы AdBlock внес Яндекс в число ресурсов, где не блокируется реклама). В общем, скандалы, интриги, расследования